# Android Debug Monitor fails to take screen shot most of the time

Tags: android

My laptop recently crashed so I had to re-install Android Device Monitor along with all the other support software for Android development. I am now using version 22.3.0.  Now when I try to get a screen shot of my app running in an emulator I get this result most of the time:

[image]

So just to be clear. This does not happen all the time, just most of the time. I estimate it happens 3 time out of 4 attempts.  This is a real pain.  Is there anything I could try to improve my chances of getting an actual screen shot 100% of the time?

Thanks

Update here's a screen shot of my emulator's setting:

[image]

Comment: The avd has which android api???

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not sure which android api the avd has.  How can I find out?

Comment: You running this on the emulator?? Or device??  Though you could go to settings, about device if i am not wrong.  And may be get the info

Comment: Once I get a screen shot I will edit my question to add the screen shot of the emulator's setting ;)

Comment: It should work m sure but then could you even try taking a screenshot having api level2.3??  Or else use command line to take a screenshot. Googling how to take a screenshot with adb command line will give you the comnand

Comment: Screenshots dont work on api 4.3 because its not added in it

Comment: Android version numbers confuse me.  Can you remind what `api 4.3` means? thanks

Comment: Jelly bean,  values 17,18